# Python modules work in imports but commands from modules not working in command line

Tags: bash, python-2.7, pyqt, python-module

I'm trying to build some QGIS plugins on my Mac (El Capitan) and installed Python using Homebrew. I've also installed SIP and PyQt4 and see them under site-packages under `/usr/local/lib/python2.7`. I can import PyQt4 after launching Python. The problem is that when I run the command `pyrcc4 -o resources.py resources.qrc`, I get "-bash: pyrcc4: command not found", and I'm pretty sure pyrcc4 came with PyQt4.

For reference:

- `which python` gives me `/usr/local/bin/python`
- `python -V` gives me Python 2.7.12
- When I run python in the terminal then import PyQt4, I get no errors.

What do I need to do to get the `pyrcc4` command to work?

I've also tried `brew install pyqt` but it kept saying the formula is not found. I need to use pyqt4 and not pyqt5.

Answer (score 0):

This error as **pyrcc4** is not present **3<sup>rd</sup>** step will create it

You need to follow these steps it will fix this issue:

```
1. brew install cartr/qt4/qt@4
2. brew install cartr/qt4/qt-legacy-formula
3. brew install cartr/qt4/pyqt@4
4. pip install lxml
5. brew install libxml2
6. git clone https://github.com/tzutalin/labelImg.git
7. cd labelImg
8. make qt4py2
9. python labelImg.py

If PyQt4 is giving error after successful installation then use this
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
```

For all other who are not using **Brew** follow this [link](https://brew.sh/)

Hope this will solve your problem. If not then let me know.